# Question about the order of cycles

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation

> Let $1 \le n \le m.$ Prove $S_m$ contains a subgroup of order $n.$
>
> Solution: Since $1 \le n \le m, \alpha  = (1, 2, 3, 4, \ldots, n) \in S_m$. By theorem $1.2.20, \operatorname{ord(a)} = n \ldots$
>
> Theorem $1.2.20$: if $\alpha$ is a permutation of a finite set, then $\operatorname{ord(a)}$ is the least common multiple of the lengths of the disjoint cycles of $\alpha.$

By the given theorem we have $n \mid \operatorname{ord(a)}$, but how do they deduce $\operatorname{ord(a)} \mid n$?

Comment: Why do you need to show ord($\alpha$) divides $n$? Isn't it enough to show, by inspection, that they are equal? i.e. apply $\alpha$ $n$ times and see that it's the identity.

Comment: @QuinnGreicius, would that mean the given theorem is redundant here?

Comment: not totally redundant -- the answer below uses it in a perfectly valid way, but it does seem a little excessive for this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cycle $\alpha$ is a disjoint cycle (because it's just one cycle). So its order is just its length, $n$.

[To be even more true to the words of the theorem, the least common multiple of the set $\{n\}$ is $n$.]

Comment: Very explicit. Exactly what I needed.